# Can I refer to current subrange when using ranges::views::chunk_by?

Tags: c++, std-ranges

I am given a random integer vector `v` and want to chunk into subranges by following criteria:

1. integers in the subrange should be contiguous and increasing by 1 (easy to check)
2. the size of the subrange should not be greater than 4 (this is hard)

```
auto result = v | ranges::views::chunk_by([](int a, int b) {
 return a + 1 == b /* && size of current chunk < 4 */;
});
```

Does anyone have idea how to do this? Is there any alternative method still using `ranges` library?

Comment: I wonder if a stateful lambda would work. `chunk_by([i = 0](int a, int b) mutable {`, and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use  `views::transform` to apply `views::chunk(4)` to each subrange and then join them:

```
  auto result = v | std::views::chunk_by([](int a, int b) {
    return a + 1 == b /* && size of current chunk < 4 */;
  }) 
    | std::views::transform(std::views::chunk(4))
    | std::views::join;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YM9TohjMx)

Comment: I really don't like that you don't have the first `|` operator on a new line. I suggest this formatting https://godbolt.org/z/sc8soGqzc i.e. a verb (`|`) object (`std:views::...`) syntax

Comment: That lambda is a really verbose way to spell `std::views::chunk(4)`.